# Magento Catalog Search Query Explanation

Tags: mysql, magento

**UPDATE**: Question answered, see [Magento Catalog Search Query Constraint Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753264/magento-catalog-search-query-constraint-error) for my follow-up question.

I'm getting foreign key constraint errors when making certain searches in the Magento catalog. Here's a query that cause that:

```
INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` 
(
    SELECT 
        '0', 
        `s`.`product_id`, 
        -(
            ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index`) AGAINST ('ip335') ) + 
            ( 5 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_1`) AGAINST('ip335') ) ) + 
            ( 3 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_2`) AGAINST('ip335') ) ) + 
            ( 2 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_3`) AGAINST ('ip335') ) ) 
        ) 

    FROM `mikkelrickycatalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` 

    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        ON `e`.`entity_id`=`s`.`product_id` 

    WHERE 
        (
            (`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%ip335%')
        ) 
        AND `s`.`store_id`='2'
) 
ON DUPLICATE 
    KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`);
```

We're using the `MikkelRicky_CatalogSearch` extension, but even the core search code produces a similar query (`INSERT/ON DUPLICATE KEY`).

I'm trying to understand this TYPE of query in SQL. I simply don't understand how INSERT statements work with DUPLICATE KEY UPDATEs. Can anyone provide some practical explanations? Thanks!

Comment: if MySQL sees that keys `query_id` and `product_id` of `catalogsearch_result` are duplicating than MySQL engine updates value `relevance = VALUES('relevance');` instead of insert

Comment: Great, that makes sense. Thanks @P0ZiTR0N. Please post that as an answer so I can give you credit. Now, I'm able to ask the next question (see my edit) about the constraint error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if MySQL sees that keys `query_id` and `product_id` of `catalogsearch_result` are duplicating than MySQL engine updates value `relevance = VALUES('relevance');` instead of insert