# Magento Catalog Search Query Constraint Error

Tags: mysql, magento

**NOTE**: This is a follow-up to [Magento Catalog Search Query Explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752464/magento-catalog-search-query-explanation)

For this query:

```
INSERT INTO `catalogsearch_result` 
(
    SELECT 
        '0', 
        `s`.`product_id`, 
        -(
            ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index`) AGAINST ('ip335') ) + 
            ( 5 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_1`) AGAINST('ip335') ) ) + 
            ( 3 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_2`) AGAINST('ip335') ) ) + 
            ( 2 * ( MATCH(`s`.`data_index_3`) AGAINST ('ip335') ) ) 
        ) 

    FROM `mikkelrickycatalogsearch_fulltext` AS `s` 

    INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
        ON `e`.`entity_id`=`s`.`product_id` 

    WHERE 
        (
            (`s`.`data_index` LIKE '%ip335%')
        ) 
        AND `s`.`store_id`='2'
) 
ON DUPLICATE 
    KEY UPDATE `relevance` = VALUES(`relevance`);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`magento_1_4`.`catalogsearch_result`, CONSTRAINT `FK_CATALOGSEARCH_RESULT_QUERY` FOREIGN KEY 
(`query_id`) REFERENCES `catalogsearch_query` (`query_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Question is: why? :)

In this case, if I just run the sub-query as a SELECT statement, I get several results back (so products are found for the given criteria). However, there are no entries on `catalogsearch_result` for any of the matching products, which would cause the above query to perform an `INSERT`. Given that, why does it throw the constraint error? Does `catalogsearch_query` first need to contain a row with a matching `query_id` record?

Comment: Does reql query have in `query_id` value and does this value exist in table `catalogsearch_query`? As you asked, first you need to insert to `catalogsearch_query` and next in other tables. You can check this for example - http://www.rndblog.com/insert-into-multiple-mysql-tables-linked-by-a-foreign-key/

Comment: Thanks again @P0ZiTR0N. As I expected, that was in fact the problem. Some extending code written by someone else had intentionally commented out the code responsible for first writing the related record to `catalogsearch_query`. So that clears up this question. Once again, if you'll add that as an answer, I'll give you the credit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to insert to `catalogsearch_query` and next in other tables. You can check [this](http://www.rndblog.com/insert-into-multiple-mysql-tables-linked-by-a-foreign-key/) for example